# How to restrict a controller access based on a logged in user's role in ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, authorization, role-base-authorization

Guys I have **4 tables** in my DB as follows

- **Functions** {id, name
- **Admin_Users** {Id, Email, Password, role_id}
- **Roles** {id, name}
- **Role_Functions** {id, role_id, function_id}

I'm using **RoR** as web development environment.

Here,

I want to restrict a controller access based on a logged in user's role (role-base-authorization), How I do this? does it requires a new table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [cancan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) gem. It's a cool gem.

Comment: Does it suites my DB structure? means I'm creating a dynamic roles

Comment: Surely, it can. Check this episode, http://railscasts.com/episodes/192-authorization-with-cancan. It's a bit old, but still good episode.